# Prevent gtk2 toggle buttons and progress bars from stretching vertically

Tags: c, gtk2

I'm trying to write an interface in GTK+2, and I can't find a way to make sure toggle buttons and progress bars won't try to fill up entire space avaiable to them.

My interface has a picture, and a bunch of progress bars and toggle buttons on the other side. If there's enough of them to make the entire vbox with them higher than the picture itself, everything is fine:

[image: interface looking correct]

However, when there isn't enough of them, they get vertically stretched, which makes them look wrong:

[image: stretched button and progress bar]

I can't find any way to make sure this doesn't happen, the only thing that I found in the documentation related to setting height of these widgets is setting their minimal height. I'm looking for a way to ensure these widgets don't try to take up all space they can.

My code is [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f7e4ba89c7b58443e3459eee4893611e). I couldn't include the placeholder image that I'm using here, but it's just a 128x128 placeholder that can be easily replaced if needed.

Comment: I am not very familiar with GTK2, but what about replacing this line `gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), current->box);` with `gtk_box_pack_start(vbox, current->box,FALSE, FALSE);`?

Comment: With some modifications (a cast to the correct pointer type and adding a border argument to the function call) this fixed my problem. Consider posting this as an answer, and I'll mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your widget for a single CPU, you add it to the parent container:

```
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER (vbox), current->box);
```

Container functions are generic for multiple types of widgets to hold children but don't allow specific adjustments.

In a box you can specify whether the available space should be added to the child widget and how it should appear.
To use this you need to change this line to:

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), current->box, FALSE, FALSE, <borderline>);
```

This should prevent the widget to be enlarged.